# Why text-based regex engines cannot handle lazy quantifiers?

Tags: regex, backtracking, finite-automata, dfa

I have came across many times that, [text-based regex engines cannot support lazy quantifiers](https://www.regular-expressions.info/engine.html#:%7E:text=features%2C%20such%20as-,lazy%20quantifiers,-and%20backreferences%2C%20can). But I could not find why. But I came to know that, they internally use DFAs, and they do not backtrack.

Then I sat down to draw a DFA for lazy quantifiers and this is what I got.
`\/\*.*\*\/`(where * is lazy)(matches C comments correctly):
([regex form](https://regex101.com/r/OvsH0z/2) of below DFA to make sure it is behaving as expected)
[image]

For comparison, I also wrote the greedy quantifier version.
`\/\*.*\*\/`(where * is greedy)(matches C comments incorrectly):
([regex form](https://regex101.com/r/ElAKRo/2) of below DFA to make sure it is behaving as expected)
[image]

*Sorry, I forgot to add start state in the diagram. Consider left-most state as start in both of them.*

Here, greedy version actually requires backing-up! Also, lazy quantifiers can be done with DFA. Did I did anything wrong? Why are there many saying text-based regex engines don't support lazy?

*PS: To keep it simple, I did not complete both of the above DFAs. To complete them, just add all the non-existent moves from every state to a new error state. Once entered error state, no exiting from it.*